# Haskell Parse Error in Helper Function

Tags: haskell

I'm just learning Haskell, and I decided to try writing my own version of `pred`, which returns the number preceding its parameter. I'm using WinGHCi and loading a file called `test.hs`.  Here is my code:

```
prev :: (Num a) => a -> a
prev x = prev' 0 x
  where prev' y z
    | (succ y) == z = y
    | otherwise = prev' (succ y) z
```

I get the error:

```
test.hs:4:5:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

---

**How does one properly write a helper function with guards?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why parse error? Indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178199/why-parse-error-indentation)

Comment: The standard answer here is to be sure you're using spaces, not tabs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern guards need to be more deeply indented—they need to be further to the right than the `p` in the definition of `prev'`.  This version doesn't give the parse error:

```
prev :: (Num a) => a -> a
prev x = prev' 0 x
  where prev' y z
            | (succ y) == z = y
            | otherwise = prev' (succ y) z
```

You're still getting a type error there, though—need more type class constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! What do you mean by type class constraints?

Comment: I got it - I need to replace `(Num a)` by something like `(Integral a)` so it can test for equality. Thanks!